# My ASP.net MVC 4 site gets slow on first request to SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.net MVC 4 site and it gets slow on the first request.
It is not high slow but pages that use to long 1000-700 ms on load, the first time it longs 8-15seg. It occurs when i wait for 10 minutes for example and come back to make a request. The web site is not on production server yet. May it be when the app pool does not receive any request it goes to sleep?.

I have configured the new AutoStart mode in framework 4:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I think it may be the first request to the SQL Server Express 2012 (in the same server).
I have set the autoclose=off in the database.

What more can i do?. How could i see what is going on the first request to avoid that slow response?.

Comment: You can use SQL Server profiler to look at the calls made to your database

Comment: Along with @dskh's suggestion, there's also MVCMiniProfiler - https://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.

Comment: its a long shot but is your conn string localhost or 127.0.0.1 ? change it to a host name, i've just had an issue where using an ip address caused a reverse dns lookup to be done.

Comment: perhaps you are using code first and your db is generated on first hit on db? Do as @dskh said and profile your sql, it's ofter there the answer to slowdowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to every one who has apported to this question.
Finally i think it has to do with the idle time configuration in the App pool.
It was set 5 min (default) and i have set it 60 min. and now it goes fine!

Thanks to this question:

[First request is very slow after website sits idle with ASP.NET MVC 3 (IIS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732484/first-request-is-very-slow-after-website-sits-idle-with-asp-net-mvc-3-iis7)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the views for faster performance.

The documentation is for MVC 3, but it should still work:

[Compile Views in Asp.Net MVC 3 with Visual Studio](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-visual-studio/)

Comment: Thank you!! i didnt know it i could compile views!

Comment: This comes from the old asp.net days where you could compile the entire web site....